# Tomcat ThreadWithAttributes causing Memory Leak

Tags: memory, tomcat, jvm, memory-leaks, yourkit

I have out of memory issues with following environment:

Tomcat 5.1.23
Using XFire WebServices Framework
JDK 1.5

Used YourKit to profile it and found out multiple instances of class org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes has huge ArrayList object (Stack Local) with java.lang.Object array containing duplicate string.

Following are some screenshots.

Any idea why ThreadWithAttributes hold references to such ArrayList objects and those strings seem to be input to software deployed in tomcat?

Does it have to do something with known memory leak issue with tomcat?

[Screenshot 1](http://gallery.me.com/memon.adnan#100026/Screen-20shot-202009-09-11-20at-208-55-27-20AM&bgcolor=black)

[Screenshot 2](http://gallery.me.com/memon.adnan#100026/Screen-20shot-202009-09-11-20at-203-43-10-20PM&bgcolor=black)

Comment: It has been two days .. no response! Looks like no one has ever experienced this before. Anyone?

Comment: Please Adnan Memon - can you explain what was the issue in your code that caused this error? We are having a similar issue. Will be great if you can share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! It was our code causing those Tomcat threads to keep the data in stack local.

Comment: Hi, we are having a similar issue (a ThreadWithAttributes of 700M!) can you please provide more information... although it's been almost a year.

Comment: It was actually internal application code not the tomcat itself.